# Eclipse Debug Mode disrupting SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure access

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, debugging, stored-procedures

We have a strange problem in our team. When a developer is using Eclipse in Debug mode, SQL Server 2005 blocks other developers from accessing a stored procedure. Debug session typically involves opening Hibernate session to persist an entity which could be accessing a stored procedure used for Primary key generation. Debugging is done in business logic code and rarely in JDBC stored procedure call.

Is there any way to configure SQL server or the stored procedure so that other developers are not blocked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure how Eclipse is doing the locking, but it sounds like you need to get each developer who will be debugging their own copy of the database.